# How to add phone logs programmatically in Android?

Tags: android

I want to add phone logs programmatically from my custom application.
Using the following code for adding phone logs, I get a new phone log in phone log list, 
but it only adds the phone number in the list, not "call type", "duration", and "Date".

What did I miss?

```
    ContentValues values = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        Info info = (Info) Variables.elementAt(i);
        int index = info.getIndex();
        String value = info.getValue();
        values = new ContentValues();
        if (value != null) {
            if (index == Constants.NUMBER_TYPE) {
                values.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE, value);
            } else if (index == Constants.CALL_TYPE) {
                values.put(CallLog.Calls.TYPE, value);
            } else if (index == Constants.DATE) {
                values.put(CallLog.Calls.DATE, value);
            } else if (index == Constants.DURATION) {
                values.put(CallLog.Calls.DURATION, value);
            }
        }
    }
    values.put(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, phoneNumber);
    activity.getContentResolver().insert(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Comment: You're putting the same object, `value`, into the map multiple times.  Why?

Comment: Sorry for incorrect code. Correct code now updated

Comment: I'd guess that `Variables` just doesn't have or won't expose the items at those indexes.  You should check.

Comment: I have already checked, all items received from Variables according to there indexes. I searched too much in Google, and some one says that it is not possible to add call logs programmatically. Now I have a another new question is this possible to add call logs programmatically.?

Answer (score 2):

I tried this in my LG P350.
Its surely works with the `android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS` permission.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE, 0);
values.put(CallLog.Calls.TYPE, CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE);
values.put(CallLog.Calls.DATE, System.currentTimeMillis());
values.put(CallLog.Calls.DURATION, 50);
values.put(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, "1234567890");
getContentResolver().insert(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, values);
```